# EF. Read back tablename set in another Convention?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've multiple conventions in my context. They overwrite each other. Is there a way ta read back a tablename set earlier?

If this convention is read first...

```
public class FirstConvention : Convention
{
    public FirstConvention()
    {
        this.Types()
            .Configure(t =>
            {
                t.ToTable("First_" + t.ClrType.Name);
            });
    }
}
```

...and then this convention is run....

```
public class SecondConvention : Convention
{
    public SecondConvention()
    {
        this.Types()
            .Configure(t =>
            {
                // is it possible to check here if the tablename is set earlier?
                t.ToTable(t.ClrType.Name + "_second");
            });
    }
}
```

...the tablename from the first convention is ofcourse overwritten. Is there a way to read the tablename in the second convention?